# Android studio Gradle icon error, Manifest Merger

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I keep seeing this message and not sure how to solve it for good.

```
Error:(43, 9) Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/new_app_icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:43:9
    is also present at com.github.erizet.signala:signala-longpolling:0.20:7:18 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:40:5 to override
:OpenBook:processDebugManifest FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':OpenBook:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Tried adding `android:replace="android:icon"` to my manifest even with my icon.

I tried deleting the  `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher` from the library but it keeps coming back when i build because its imported from maven

Any ideas ?

Comment: This issue occurs when issue in the manifest file tags. Please check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39509659/2732632

Comment: I faced the same issue when i added duplicate permissions in manifest.

Answer (score 360, accepted):

It seems to be the fault of the mainfest Merger tool for gradle.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Solved it by adding to my manifest tag  `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Then added  `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"` to the application tag

This tells the merger to use my manifest icon and theme and not of other libraries

Comment: The problem still persists for me. Working in Android Studio 1.1.

Comment: Worked for me. Perfect Solution, Basically they have upgraded the Migration system and not allowing the old manifest merger system. To avoid conflicts between elements to be merged, some markers have been added to guide the Manifest Merger.

Comment: Working in Android Studio 1.2

Comment: It worked to me with `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` on `<manifest>` tag and `tools:replace="icon"` on `<application>` tag

Comment: If some body still has the same problem and this solution is not working, then you can try to add "android:allowBackup" to the  tools:replace like this (Ex. tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:icon,android:theme")

Comment: did you add  > tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme" < to the library or to your app ?

Comment: I just added the jar in Libs folder instead to give the dependency in .gradle file.

Comment: Latest versions of android 2.0. not working. Whoever answered should update this Q if he meant saving generations else it will be useless soon

Comment: Studio 2.2 from today all having this  and nt working this issue

Comment: not working for Android Studio 2.2 with gradle 2.2.0.

Comment: Working on Android Studio 2.2.3, you rocks!

Comment: Note: The posted link has since been replaced / migrated to the new URL: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#attribute_markers

Answer (score 57):

I have same issue , I fix it like this by adding `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the top of mainfest file , and add `tools:replace="android:icon"` to be look like

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  // add tools line here 
    package="yourpackage">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon"> ///add this line 

.....

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: not working for Android Studio 2.2 and gradle 2.2.0.

Comment: brilliant answer

Answer (score 12):

i have same error , just this code solve my problem , i want to share with you :

in **`Manifest.xml`** :

- **add this code in top of your xml file :**

  `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
- **Then added :**

  `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:label,android:name"`   to the application tag

Comment: @DysaniazzZ , it's not depending on Android Studio . see message log .

Comment: Okay, I'll see.

Comment: @Funwise , check your message log , i think it's not depending on android studio .

Comment: @adnan9011, my problem was having duplicate permissions in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 9):

The answer of shimi_tap is enough.
What to be remembered is that choosing only what you need. Choose from {icon, name, theme, label}.
I added `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"`, it does not work. I added `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:label,android:name"`, it does not work. It works when I added `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:label"`. So find out what the conflict exactly is in your manifest files.

Comment: not working for Android Studio 2.2 and gradle 2.2.0.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your manifest tag, and then you need to add `tools:replace="android:icon"` **before** `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`.

Answer (score 3):

This error also occurs when your app's minSdk is higher than any library's minSdk.

```
app's minSdk >= libraries minSdk
```

Comment: so, what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

**GOT THE SOLUTION AFTER ALOT OF TIME GOOGLING**

just get your **ic_launcher** and paste it in your drawables folder,

Go to your manifest and **change android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"**

Clean your project and rebuild

**Hope it helps you**

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem changing the icon from drawable to mipmap.

I only missed the line

`tools:replace="android:icon"`

in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason android studio doesn't like calling app icon from drawable folder. So in that case I created mipmap resource directory under res folder.

**Right click res folder > new > android resource directory > resource type: mipmap** and now drop any icon in there then reference that into manifest file. Sharing this since this method worked for me.

**android:icon:@drawable/ic_launcher"**

to

**android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"**

Comment: for me setting the style seemed best `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`  see -> https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/4d284b11b5bca3054bddf8f511e49ae9

Answer (score 1):

If nothing of that work, close Android Studio. Go on app/src/main, open the file AndroidManifest.xml in a text editor (like sublime), remove/replace the erros lines, save and reopen android studio.

Answer (score 1):

> When an attribute value contains a placeholder (see format below), the
>   manifest merger will swap this placeholder value with an injected
>   value. Injected values are specified in the build.gradle.   The syntax
>   for placeholder values is ${name} since @ is reserved for links. After
>   the last file merging occurred, and before the resulting merged
>   android manifest file is written out, all values with a placeholder
>   will be swapped with injected values. A build breakage will be
>   generated if a variable name is unknown.

from http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Build-error

Answer (score 0):

Shimi_tap's answer is the right way to fix the problem. If you want to use old merger tool you can add this to build.gradle file

android {
 useOldManifestMerger true
 }

Comment: "In 1.0, we removed the ability to invoke the old manifest merger. .."
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Comment: Could not find method useOldManifestMerger() for arguments [true] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue occurred after updating Google Play Services. One of the libraries I was using incorporated this library using the "+" in its gradel reference, like

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`

This created an issue because the min version targeted by that library was less than what was targeted by the current version of Google Play Services. I found this by simply looking in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.gradle` change MinSDK, for example:

- `build.gradle` (Module: app)

  - before: `minSdkVersion 9`
  - after:  `minSdkVersion 14`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solution mentioned above

in **`Manifest.xml`** :

- **add this code in top of your xml file within manifest tag:**

  `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
- **Then added :**

  `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:label,android:name"`   to the application tag

but none of it worked. I needed to delete a xml file which was situated in

> mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml

I was testing the application in

**Samsung Galaxy 8** with OS version **8.0.0**

is it really a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Within the AndroidManifest.xml file, add the following to the `application` node:

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory,android:icon,android:theme,android:label,android:name"
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you add a third-party library with @drawable/ic_launcher attribute thus android merger is unable to differentiate your app icon attribute and the library's attribute. To solve this add this line in your manifest file under the application tag

```
tools:replace="android:icon"
```

Answer (score 0):

And update for Android Studio - Arctic Fox

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    // DOCS: This is where we add the xmlns:tools reference
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app">
    // Permissions would go here
    // ...
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        ...
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        // DOCS: If you dont add this entry the xmlns:tools ref will not be found
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```