# Manifest merger failed when trying to add my own logo to android app - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-manifest

I tried to add my own icon to my app in Android Studio and I encountered a Manifest merger fail. I fount an identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger) but his answer is not working for me. I tried adding `tools:replace="android:icon"` and `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"` (on 2 separate occasions of course) but no change.

This is the error Android Studio is keep giving me.

```
Error:(12, 9) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/footynews_logo_new) from AndroidManifest.xml:12:9
    is also present at com.arasthel:gnavdrawer-library:1.1.4:4:45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5 to override
Error:(12, 9) Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/footynews_logo_new) from AndroidManifest.xml:12:9
```

EDIT : I just found out even though I thought the app was using the ic_launcher in my project directory, it is actually using the ic_launcher in one of the libraries I'm using. How do I force the app to use my launcher icon instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio Gradle icon error, Manifest Merger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger)

Answer (score 19):

```
tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
```

should work. Hope you added

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

If this is not working you have another option. Use the old manifest merger. Add this in your `build.gradle` file

```
android { useOldManifestMerger true }
```

You can find more information [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger).

Comment: I did add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools.
It turns out a library I used (GNavDrawer) had a Manifest and somehow, my project was forced to use its ic_launcher (or I think it is). I resolved this issue by changing that manifest file (although I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do it)

Comment: "In 1.0, we removed the ability to invoke the old manifest merger. .."
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Answer (score 5):

Add two line in manifest file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> <!--Add this line-->

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="icon, label"/> <!--Add this line-->
</manifest>
```