# imported projects give error in android studio 1.2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

i use android studio 1.2.1.1 and it doesn't give me any error for new projects.
but for imported projects it gives me an warning about mismatched Encoding ([this issue](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding)). i changed project and IDE encoding to UTF-8 and this warning doesn't appear any more.
but , after that , it gives me this error.

```
F:\Work\workspace\NITask\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.
F:\Work\workspace\NITask\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

and in these projects , there isn't R class in my main module.
i read many questions like [finished with non zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value) but wasn't useful

update:
after clean project , it gives me many error about my resources like this:

```
AAPT err(1779619686): F:\Work\workspace\NITask\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\shadow.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

Comment: Error log clearly mentions that,its missing ic_launcher page in "drawable-hdpi" folder. 
Copy paste your launcher icon to that folder of res directory. And clean build your project.

Comment: I don't think it's the matter of mismatching encoding. This error happens when there is something wrong with importings

Comment: Change your IDE version like android 22.0.1 to 21. or 19

Comment: this folder has ic_launcher file @m0rpheu5

Comment: i make this project in android studio 1.0 and import it in new android studio without any change @SilentKnight

Comment: i changed buildToolsVersion but wasn't useful @Jack

Comment: http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding this is the problem @Alex

Comment: have you changed your gradle build version ??
 buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"  ??

Comment: i changed buildToolsVersion '22.0.1' to  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2" but same error. @m0rpheu5

Comment: @AlexMercer Delete the intermediates and generated folders and rebuild the app again. This should work

Comment: @m0rpheu5 , tnx a lot m0rpheu5 !
it works finally !!

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**FIRST :**

```
libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

iCCP are just warnings. they are not errors and they dont failed your app build so ignore it.

**SECOND :**

The actual error is

```
F:\Work\workspace\NITask\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.
F:\Work\workspace\NITask\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
```

This error may occur because of 3rd party libraries uses ic_launcher in thr  library.
You can solve this by :

**1)** clean your project and rebuild it.

**2)** create a folder "**mipmap-mdpi**","**mipmap-hdpi**","**mipmap-xhdpi**","**mipmap-xxhdpi**" and copy the ***ic_launcher*** icons and place it in the respective folder based on the sizes.

```
res/
mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png (48x48 pixels)
mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png (72x72)
mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png (96x96)
mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (144x144)
mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (192x192)
```

give reference to the icon in your xml file as

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

The reason for the mipmap folder (According to [Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)) :

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the
>   drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from
>   the device’s current density.

**3)** If above solution doesn't solve, then rename the **drawable-*** folder as **drawable-*-v4** (*where * is mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi or xxhdpi*) and place all your drawables in them.

```
res/ 
drawable-mdpi-v4/
drawable-hdpi-v4/
drawable-xhdpi-v4/
drawable-xxhdpi-v4/
```

after this do the **1)** point and try

Answer (score 25):

I had same issue , I fix it by adding 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" to the top of mainfest file , and add tools:replace="android:icon" to application tag.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  // add tools line here 
    package="yourpackage">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon"> //add this line 

.....

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This did it for me.

Comment: nice and clean!

Comment: The error occurred after I added a library to my project. Think that lib requires a mipmap folder and ic_launcher, so this is the best solution to it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

change the icon drawable-hdpi some time icon crashed using any other icon same name problem solved

Click Open file encoding setting -> project encoding ->cnaged UTf-8

Comment: i change my icon with new filename but it gives me same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue, chances are that you are working on `Windows` which has a character limit of `260 characters.` Check your path to your workspace has, chances are that it is crossing the character limits If not then it comes to the problem when `gradle` start merging your dependencies.

So during this merging process, your full path becomes `\todo-mvp\todoapp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4` in addition to `Path_up_to_your_workscpace`, as the window had a limit of 260 characters scripts starts falling out as it is not able to do write operations.

**FIX**

Try to shorten the path that leads to your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,  add

> tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"

to application tag

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="co.darkwing.bookingapp" >
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_darkwing_co"
            tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"> //ADD THIS BIT
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```