# Android Error After Update Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

There is an update for Android Studio version 1.3. After update, i was opened my Project and when i try to run it in emulator, there is an error.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72221Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library
:app:prepareComGithubSatyanSugar131Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(1035023611): C:\Users\Jeems\Documents\JoelMobile2\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(906211783): C:\Users\Jeems\Documents\JoelMobile2\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(672280396): C:\Users\Jeems\Documents\JoelMobile2\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(604063224): C:\Users\Jeems\Documents\JoelMobile2\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\Jeems\Documents\JoelMobile2\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.
C:\Users\Jeems\Documents\JoelMobile2\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jeems\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Is there any solutions to fix this problem?

Comment: clean and built again, it may work

Comment: i've tried to build the project but it still produce an error

Comment: try built -> make module app and rebuilt

Comment: did it asked to delete some old files?. because they were causing some conflicts with this new update. It prompted me with that and I selected delete files. what did you select?.. I think it is just those old files failing your build. try deleting those old files and then do build & clean.

Comment: @govindpatel when i delete the file which duplicated, its fixed.

Comment: This may help anyone! Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32032462/2165382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a duplicate file. The error is shown in the build log

```
drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.
drawable-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
```

remove one of them.

Comment: Why it is a problem when the file is duplicate? and when i remove one of them (the exact file which is my app icon) the error is fixed

Comment: Happy to hear.Go ahead

Comment: Everything in "drawable-xxhdpi-v4" can be moved to "drawable-xxhdpi" and the -v4 folder can be removed

Answer (score 2):

**Build > Clean Project** Then `Gradle` &`Restart` Project .

Comment: @JeemsTerry did you checked Kuffs answer