# Manifest merger error in Paytm library by adding in dependencies

Tags: android, android-manifest, paytm, manifest-merging

While integrating Paytm,i used dependency library instead of jar file as per latest release by paytm team.i am getting below error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/app_icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:55:9-42
>       is also present at [com.paytm.pgsdk:pgsdk:1.0.6] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:52:5-149:19 to override.

I am using this theme,Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

**My android Manifest file.**

```
 <application
        android:name="com.theoteq.volley.Singleton_volley"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAp5wr5YkhjgjggjjggjkgkgkELY" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Splash_Screen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Login_Screen" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Otp_Screen" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Car_Type" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Address_Type" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.AddInsuranceActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.PickUp_Map" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Date_Time" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Job_Review" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Confirmation" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.ProfileView" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Locate_Us" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.CarSelection" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Search_Detailing" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Search_Wash" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.map.Search" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Search_MonthPackage" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" />
        <receiver android:name="com.theoteq.service.SmsReciever">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.GCMIntentService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.ConnectionReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Search_Two"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search__two" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.About_Us_Webview" />
        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.WebActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.Payment_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_payment_"
          />
        <!--<meta-data-->
            <!--android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"-->
            <!--android:value="6100d285268932be90ce189b361a7560b69artyu" />-->

        <activity android:name="com.theoteq.xpresscarspa.About_Us_View"></activity>

        -keepclassmembers class com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmWebView$PaytmJavaScriptInterface {
        public *;
        }
    </application>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_primary_color_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent" >@color/app_accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item> 
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/cursorColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you show us your AndroidManifest.xml file in the question?

Comment: `tools:replace="android:icon` try adding this in your `application` tag in `manifest`

Comment: @DarshanPania i shared in question.

Comment: This is happening because the library is using the same icon name as your application. You need to google before posting here as SO has answers to this question. for eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393726/imported-projects-give-error-in-android-studio-1-2-1-1)..

Comment: As Somesh said the library is using the same icon name as your app, the `tools:replace` in your AndroidManifest will let the build script know to use your app's icon instead of the library's icon

Comment: @AbdulKawee i am getting this error,if i use "tools:replace="android:icon". Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: share your `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` style here

Comment: @AbdulKawee Check the style used by me in question

Comment: @DarshanPania I changed app icon name,stil i am getting same error

Comment: Does your `SplashScreen` or any `activity` is using `ActionBarActivity` as parent activity?

Comment: @AbdulKawee no .I am using this one.<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: @RajaSankar i am not talking about style . i am talking about activities

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167145/discussion-between-raja-sankar-and-abdul-kawee).

Comment: @Somesh Kumar Gurjar   getting same error,even i changed image name.Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/app_icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:55:9-42 is also present at [com.paytm.pgsdk:pgsdk:1.0.6] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:52:5-149:19 to override.

Comment: Don't change the name, just add `tools:replace="android:icon"` to your AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by updating Paytm library file in build gradle.