# Unable to use android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" in Manifest after play services 7.5.0

Tags: android, google-play-services, drawable, mipmaps

I have recently update play services using dependencies
 `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`
My app icon launcher is in `@mipmap/ic_launcher"` but this is showing error in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Should i again place this icon in `drawable` or else ?
Help me to find out the solution.

**UPDATE:** Here is Messages from Android studio

```
Error:(17, 9) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:17:9
    is also present at com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0:13:9 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:5 to override
Error:(17, 9) Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:17:9
D:\3cworkspace\PeakPerformance\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: please post your manifest file along with error you are seeing.

Comment: Check this answer and it may work with you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24507129/3679005

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add following line to the application tag

```
tools:replace="android:icon"
```

Also import `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to manifest file.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution for ic_launcher app icon conflict.

Comment: This should definitely be marked as the correct answer. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

under application tag in Manifest,worked for me.

```
androidtools:replace='android:icon'
android:name=".ApplicationSubClass"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
tools:replace="android:icon" > //HERE
```