# App launcher Icons suddently not working Android Studio

Tags: android

I set my compileSDKVersion to 27, and now I get a default (b&w) icon on my Android App

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to invalidate the the cache and restart.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that

Comment: try to rename image and get it again, sometimes its create issue because of cache.

Comment: Just recreated as "icons.png", but it's rubbish as a solution

Comment: are you able to get image from drawable folder?

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30753704/5110595)

Answer (score 2):

You also need to use **`android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`**

> [Round Icon Resources](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1)

When a launcher requests an app icon, the framework returns either android:icon or android:roundIcon, depending on the device build configuration. Because of this, apps should make sure to define both android:icon and android:roundIcon resources when responding to launcher intents.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
 does the same: i.e. default icon

Comment: Apps can now define circular launcher icons - But I don't want a circular icon!

Comment: @stevenpcurtis but users want that. Your icon will look bad among other circular icons when a user switches launcher icons in round mode. You will hurt only your UX by trying to workaround round icons.

Comment: @3mpty agree with u

Answer (score 0):

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`
```