# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android

I am trying to implement GCM by a tutorial and first resolved the permission problem, but after that this error is coming where I haev tried seveal link on stackoverflow, is that related to my permission declaration. pleaes help me to resolve that issue.

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.akash.gcm5">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.akash.gcm5.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.akash.gcm5.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".GCMMainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GCMMessageView" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.akash.gcm5" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

App GRADLE file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.akash.gcm5"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'


}
```

Comment: try this answer ...... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24507129/3678308

Comment: i have already implemented that replace icon

Comment: @Akash how did you solved this problem