# Unable to create apk. Error:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. >

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I keep getting this error while trying to build the apk.

**ERROR**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

And in the Event Logs, it simply says "2:58:21 PM Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages'"

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.ankit.mrestro">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

        <permission android:name="com.example.ankit.mrestro.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsg.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            tools:replace="android:value"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAfg6F4I6Ee-E6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

             <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.ankit.mrestro;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOGUE_REQUEST = 9001;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    Button bLogout;
    EditText etFName, etLName, etAge, etEmail, etUserName;
    UserLocalStorage userLocalStorage;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etFName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFName);
        etLName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLName);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);

        bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
        bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
        userLocalStorage = new UserLocalStorage(this);


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        if (authenticate() == true) {
            DisplaysUserDetails();
        }

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.ankit.mrestro/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    private boolean authenticate() {
        return userLocalStorage.getUserLoggedIn();

    }

    private void DisplaysUserDetails() {
        User user = userLocalStorage.GetLoggedInUser();
        etUserName.setText(user.UserName);
        etFName.setText(user.FirstName);
        etLName.setText(user.LastName);
        etAge.setText(user.Age + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bLogout:
                userLocalStorage.ClearUserData();
                userLocalStorage.SetUserLoggedIn(false);
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOGUE_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to google play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        return false;


    }


}
```

I want to display the "Ready to Map" toast while running the app on my device. What should I do to fix the error?

**GRADLE**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ankit.mrestro"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you try to first clean and then run your project, sometimes it helps

Comment: Where is your error log?

Comment: Like I said, it simply says "You can find the errors in the 'Messages'" in the Error Log.

Comment: Edit your gradle.build file as well since you're using Android Studio. Manifest values are overridden during build.

Comment: @RajithShanika How do I do that? Please help, I'm new to android development...

Comment: @Bik there's a file named build.gradle in your project. Post it in your question and check whether sdk versions differ from the manifest.

Comment: I see. The min and target sdk are different in gradle and manifest! I'll fix that and see if it helps. Thanks. :)

Comment: The problem still persists!

Comment: @RajithShanika  ...

Comment: 2:58:21 PM Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages': What does it say in the 'Messages' window?

Comment: @RajithShanika In Event Log it says to "see Messages" and in Messages the "ERROR" is displayed..the one I've posted at the top.

Comment: Check this SO question [Android studio Gradle icon error, Manifest Merger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger) and [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14?rq=1), if it can help you :)

Comment: Seems like those solutions address some other problem, it doesn't fix mine! :(