# Manifest Merger error - tools:replace not working

Tags: android, android-manifest

## Update:

I have tried everything. Is there something wrong with Manifest merger tool?

- tools:replace
- tools:remove
- tools:ignore
- tools:node

## Unable to resolve the following error:

```
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Iknowthis2\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-36
Error: Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-36 is also present at [com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.1.5] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).     
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"'to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-73:19 to override.

D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Iknowthis2\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-36
Error:  Attribute application@supportsRtl value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-36 is also present at [com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.1.5] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-35 value=(true).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-73:19 to override.
```

## App's Original Manifest.xml - Before tools:replace

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xyz">

    <!-- Include following permission if you load images from Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Include following permission if you want to cache images on SD card -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".ABC"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute">


        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SignInActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## Library's Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sackcentury.shinebuttonlib">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: instead of  **tools:remove="allowBackup,supportsRtl** try with  **'tools:replace="android:allowBackup,supportsRtl"'**

Comment: Tried both. Same error.

Comment: did you go through it?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest

Comment: okay refer it now...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger

Comment: This is looking good. I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: but it seems you need to change the **android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"** to **android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"** if you don't use backup..

Comment: Well, I don't need to change. This link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger gave me the solution.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In my case,

removing `tools:ignore` from the Manifest files and adding `tools:replace="allowBackup,supportsRtl"` worked for me.

## Update:

One more solution looks promising, however I never tried it.

```
 <application
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  <-- added tools on application tag
    android:name=".ABC"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme"
    tools:replace="allowBackup,supportsRtl"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute">
```

Comment: Actually the magic will happen if you remove tools:ignore, because tools:replace has been included. Both can not work together well!!

Comment: removing tools:ignore worked for me , thanks it was driving me crazy :)

Comment: When i add my custom dependency module library, my App run and Every time crashed with throw IllegalStateException

java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: This will not work if you keep the  android:fullBackupContent="false". It's not a boolean attribute. see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles

Answer (score 9):

As I know, we can't use both `tools:replace` and `tools:ignore`. So you might remove one from your AndroidManifest.xml declaration.

Answer (score 3):

**It working fine for me.My manifest files look like:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 package="package name">

 <application       
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"       
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="allowBackup,supportsRtl"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute">

    </application>

  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in Manifest file -

Just add tools:replace="android:allowBackup" in application Tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.exampleapp">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
</application>
```

Comment: Not a solution because default value is set to `true`, meaning, your app can be backed-up! Read here > https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup Hence, if you want to disable that feature, you have to handle this.

Answer (score -3):

Just add tools:replace = "android:allowBackup" in your application tag in the Manifest. This will work.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. Please make sure your answer is offering a new solution which does not already exist on the question.