# failed to build after implementing implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'

Tags: android

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

//error//
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-24:19 to override.

Comment: Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' at AndroidManifext.xml or  convert your project to androidx

Comment: how do i convert to androidx  and wha is the cause of problem

Comment: On the top menu go to Refactor -> Migrate to Androidx

Comment: i have added the tool and now im experiencing Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:7 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 6 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

Comment: i think this would be helpful :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285678/manifest-merger-error-toolsreplace-not-working/39323808