# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@usesCleartextTraffic value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-44

Tags: android

This is the error I get when I add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the`AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@usesCleartextTraffic value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-44
is also present at [com.payu.custombrowser:payu-custom-browser:7.5.1] AndroidManifest.xml:17:18-54 value=(false).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-181:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer lies in your question body. You have same attribute `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in two different `AndroidManifest.xml` files in your project. So simply resolve the issue by adding `tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"` to your application tag:

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic">
 
 //...

</application>
```

Comment: For me, adding above command showed another error `The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element
type "application" is not bound.` resolved by 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39323808/4353782