# Changing First Activity in App

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to change the first `Activity` of my app and I believe I would just have to change in the `Manifest` under the Activity tag.

Right now I'm trying to change it to Main2Activity.

```
<activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I run this I get the error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I'm unsure how to go about fixing this. It works fine if I leave it as MainActivity though.

Class I'm trying to add

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}

public void multiplayerView(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}

public void campaignView(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

}

Comment: This worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger

Comment: Include the errors in logcat. That way it is easier to help you

Comment: Show the `java` file of that Activity

Comment: I just tried that again and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Include the Activity's `.java` file. You might need to also change the `class` name in the file to `Main2Activity` and the name of the file to `Main2Activity.java`

Comment: `public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    public void multiplayerView(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    public void campaignView(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}`

for some reason all R references are now not recognized. Tried a rebuild and clean

Comment: Include it in the question

Comment: "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, **see logs**" ..so what is in the logs?

Comment: Try changing the file name to `Main2Activity.java`. But note that using numbers as Java file names is not recommended.

Comment: I'm guessing its the event logs. It just says it finished with an error. I'm wondering if there are other logs that I don't know about to check though.

Comment: Where exactly would I change that? should I refactor Main2Activity?

Comment: Try renaming the file

Comment: @KritixiLithos I just did and it didn't seem to do anything new

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Pay attention to 2 "Activity" tags. I think your manifest should look like this.
Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Activity (as you mentioned. nothing special):

```
package ir.webarena.test01;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    public void multiplayerView(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    public void campaignView(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```