# using circular seekbar in android studio

Tags: android, seekbar

I tried to use circular seekbar in android studio and I found [this](https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc)

and I execute every thing he said
the gradle is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the build.gradle(Module app) is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abdelfattha.mohamed.hamai"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
  }
}

   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
    core:2.2.2', 
    {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'

  }
```

the problem is it gives me error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=
(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:9-43
is also present at [com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1] AndroidManifest.xml:36:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-25:19 to override.
```

I wish someone helps me to find the error because I am new in this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an answer inside error message:

`Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-25:19 to override.`

Comment: Adding this within my application tag in the manifest highlighted `tools` red and said "Namespace 'tools' is not bound"

Comment: Nvm, this solved it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger