# Manifest Merger Failed.

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/appiconnew) from AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-42
>       is also present at [com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-136:19 to override.

Can Anyone Help Please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger this might be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following in  tag of manifest file:

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one
on Application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
     tools:replace="android:icon"
</application>
```